# completely removing a file from git repo (from a certain point in time)

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I've got a repo with about 2030 commits. At around commit 2000 a file was modified which caused it's size to travel from about 20M to 1.2 GB accidently. Is it possible to rewrite the history to remove this file but only from commit 2000? (I dont want to lose prior history of this file)

I was thinking git-filter-branch, but couldnt see a way to tell it the "from commit" -  is it possible?

Cheers
Mike

Answer (score 2):

The man page for git-filter-branch contains the conclusive and authoritative example for this.

If you want to stop rewriting before a certain commit, say before `tag01`:

```
git-filter-branch ......  -- master ^tag01
```

Substitute what you already have for the dots. tag01 may instead be any commit-ish (revspec)

PS: if you use tags don't forget `--tag-name-filter cat` to rewrite these too

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you

1. Create a branch `new` at commit 2000, where you don't modify this file to a 1.2 GB file
2. Rebase `master` to `new`, with merge option `-Xtheirs`
3. Garbage collect the repository to save disk space.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a faster, simpler alternative to `git-filter-branch` designed for removing large files or private data from Git repos.

Download [the executable jar](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#download) (requires Java 6 or above) and run this command:

> $ java -jar bfg.jar  --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100MB  my-repo.git

Anything over 100MB in size (that isn't in your *latest* commit's file hierarchy) will be totally removed from your repository's history. All the versions of the file which are smaller than 100MB will be left alone, as specified in the question.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*